# Apple Wallet Event Pass - Device registration

Tags: wallet

We created a wallet pass and sent the wallet pass invitation email to end-users. However, there was an issue with the back-end APIs which prevented the Apple pass from automatically calling the device registration API.
The question I have is, do we need to re-inform all user to reinstall the Pass, or will the Pass automatically try re-registering by calling the device API.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have worded your question possibly describes an impossible situation.  A valid pass will always attempt to register. You state that your API was the issue, but an issue with a web service implementation would not prevent devices attempting to call it.

If the pass.json contains a valid https `webServiceURL` an `authenticationToken`, it will call the device registration endpoint after it has been added to the user's wallet.  If the device does not get a 201 or 200 response, it will continue to retry, progressively backing off from every few seconds, to every few days for a period of around 2 weeks.

Therefore, if your pass.json contained the correct information; assuming that the issue was with your device registration endpoint and assuming that you picked up and addressed the issue quickly, then you should see device registrations coming in without having to do anything.

If it took longer than a couple of weeks or if you want to accelerate the process, you could ask your users to toggle the Automatic Notifications setting on the back of the pass.  This will force the device to attempt a re-registration.

If however, the pass does not contain a `webServiceURL`, or if the `webServiceURL` was incorrect, then the device will not call back, or will call the incorrect endpoint.  In this case, the only option is to have your users reinstall the pass.  In this case, it is not your API that is causing the problem, but your passes.

Comment: HI @PassKit, thanks for your response. The pass.json is correctly referring to the webServiceUrl. However, the API server was down, thus preventing the device registration API from being called.  Regarding retries, could you please point me to any documentation?.

Comment: There is no documentation that I am aware of, but if you monitor your APi and also turn on PassKit logging from the developer menu. You can see it n your API logs and in the phone console, exactly what the phone does when it fails registration.  Also take a look a what the devices are posting to the log endpoint of the web service

Comment: Yes. I did check the logs and I could see the device registration APIs being called. I was trying to find out the retry policy, so we can reach out to users for whom the pass may have given up the retry.  Thanks for the information.